# Host website from webserver without changing public IP

Tags: networking, dns, ip

Is there any way without a public IP I can make my web server feed outside requests and host my website over it? I don’t have a public IP address at all neither static nor dynamic. I am not sure about the process but my brother says if there is no public IP then you can’t. There is not way you can do it. Is that true?

I have read some answers on SuperUser itself which says that there is way you can always keep your public IP pointed with some services like Free Dynamic DNS. But, that too has word `public` in it. Please clear out this whole confusion and make this concept clear. Thanks.

Comment: This kind of depends on where it's situated but is almost always possible if you have the network authority, but if you have a server that is inside a network that is internet accessible (which it has to be if you can reach the outside world), you would need to forward a port on your router to your web server and your public ip (which must exist to be able to access the world) could be hooked into one of the dynamic dns services.  Note: This could be fairly insecure though, you'll want to do lots more research.

Comment: In order for you to have access to the internet, you must have a public IP.  There are occasions where your public IP is shared among many, more often in mobile networks.  What does your router say its internet facing IP address is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way without a public IP I can make my web server feed outside requests and host my website over it?

No, so long as "outside requests" means "requests from the internet."

If you mean you want computers on the same network (e.g. in your home or office) to access your web server, then yes, but only those computers could use your web server, not computers on the internet (this requires a public IP). You would use your server's private network IP (e.g. `192.168.1.xxx`) to access that web server (you would type this IP address into the browser bar).

> I don’t have a public IP address[.]

If you can access the internet, you have a public IP. You wrote this post on the internet. If you can connect your server the same way as the computer you wrote your post on, you will have a public IP for that server you can (potentially) use.

**Dynamic DNS**

All computers on the internet have public IP address' such as `172.217.17.131` (Google). Computers use these addresses to communicate with each other.

You can think of these numbers like phone numbers. You can dial your friend at 1-903-234-5678, but that is hard to remember. So is typing `172.217.17.131` in your browser to get to Google.

If you think about modern cell phones, what do we have instead of numbers? We have contacts. Rather than dialing 1-903-234-5678 to call "Leroy Jenkins", we just push a contact button and the number is dialed for us.

And while not quite the same, it's easy to think of DNS in a similar fashion. DNS is a way to make sure that when you type `google.com` into the search bar, you get back the information stored at `172.217.17.131`.

The problem is, sometimes the IP addresses (phone numbers) change. This is especially true for home internet connections. What a Dynamic DNS service does it automatically "updates" the IP address associated with a domain name (like `google.com`).

Using the phone analogy, a Dynamic DNS service would be like an app on your phone that could update Leroy's contact information automatically every time he changed his number (so when you pressed the "call contact" button, you always got his current number, not his old one).